# Adjacent divs with angled borders?

Tags: css, html, css-shapes

I want to create two divs which are floated left to each other, however with a slanted angled border separating them.  I've attached a picture to demonstrate what I mean.

Does anyone know if something like this is possible with CSS (cutting off the content with an overflow:hidden I guess)

[image: adjacent div with slanted side]

These divs need to contain images that get cut off by the border, here is an example :

[image: divs with images and slanted adjacent sides]

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support? Do you need to support older versions of IE?

Comment: @thirtydot dont need to support old IE :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this

```css
.left, .right {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
  float: left;
}

.left:after {
  content: '';
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 60px;
  width: 100px;
}

.right:before {
  content: '';
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #000;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"> </div>
<div class="right"> </div>
```

---

**UPDATE** with images

```css
.left, .right {
    background: #000 url('http://lorempixel.com/300/100');
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
}

.left:after {
    content: '';
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid #fff;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0 solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    right: 0;
}

.right {
    background: #000 url('http://lorempixel.com/200/100');
    width: 150px;
}

.right:before {
    content: '';
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"> </div>
<div class="right"> </div>
```

Comment: looks good, but one caveat.  I actually want the div to have an image in it which will get cut off by the angled margin.  When I add a photo to your code it doesnt maintain the angle :(

Comment: that wasn't in the requirements :)

Comment: you are correct, I've updated the original post to better describe what I was looking for.  Thanks for the effort!

Comment: This is dope man. Well done

Comment: This is great but how do you edit this code to work with fluid heights? So if the left hand div has 2 paragraphs of text (length of which could change) how do you ensure the angle stays 100% height? Currently it doesn't.

Answer (score 16):

All of the solutions so far depend on having a really thick angled border to divide the photos.

To avoid this you'd make a container and skew it. Then counter skew the image in the opposite direction.

Here's a CodePen http://cdpn.io/azvsA, but the gist of it is as follows:

```
.container {
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform (skewX(-20deg));
}

.image {
  transform (skewX(20deg));
}
```

Comment: this has the downside that the left side and the right outer side are angled aswell see https://imgur.com/a/3gYE3s5

Answer (score 4):

You can write like this:

```
.left, .right {
    background: #000 url('http://lorempixel.com/300/100');
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
}
.left{
    z-index:1;
}
.parent{
    overflow:hidden;
}

.right {
    background: #000 url('http://lorempixel.com/200/100');
    width: 150px;
}
.left:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    border-right:20px solid #fff;
    top:-25px;
    bottom:-10px;
    left:0;
    right:-10px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(10deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(10deg);
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/EJxFg/4/