# How to do a custom border shape with CSS3

Tags: css, webkit

I'm just wondering if this shape I have in the image url is doable in css3 with webkit.

[image]

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568334/css-to-produce-adjacent-divs-with-angled-borders

Comment: **FIDDLE!** http://jsfiddle.net/qhxLu/ - **SOURCE** http://www.css3shapes.com/

Comment: i think you got your solution, so choose an answer to mark as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a good source for CSS shapes](http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-different-shapes-in-css)

Just edit the class properties to your liking to get desired shape

CSS:

```
.parallelogramRight {
     width:100px; 
     height:100px; 
     border:1px solid #000; 
     background:yellow;
     transform: skew(-20deg); 
     -o-transform: skew(-20deg); 
     -moz-transform: skew(-20deg); 
     -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that website got what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the transform: skew() property.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tkdyx

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

```
-moz-transform: skewX(-23deg);
-webkit-transform: skewX(-23deg);
-o-transform: skewX(-23deg);
-ms-transform: skewX(-23deg);
transform: skewX(-23deg);
```

Comment: This is a pretty simple solution.

Comment: Great everyone thanks for your input and suggestions.