# Angled border separating li elements

Tags: html, css

I want to create horizontal navigation using li elements. Li elements would be separated by border angled 45 degrees. I found this example:

[image]

This looks great, but how to get this?

Comment: Here is what you are looking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568334/css-to-produce-adjacent-divs-with-angled-borders

Comment: Found this earlier, but I can't manage to apply angle to left side of first li node, and for the right side of last li node...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CSS:

```
   li {
        float: left;
        background: #ccc;
        margin-right: 50px;
    }
    li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 40px;
        padding: 0 8px;
        color: #444;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    }
    li > a:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        border: 20px solid #ccc;
        border-left-color: transparent;
        border-top-color: transparent;
        right: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
    li > a:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        border: 20px solid #ccc;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }





    li:first-child > a {
        background: #aaa;
    }
    li:first-child > a:after {
        border-top-color: #aaa;
        border-left-color: #aaa;
    }

    li:last-child > a {
        background: #ddd;
    }
    li:last-child > a:before{
        border-right-color: #ddd;
        border-bottom-color: #ddd;
    }
    li:last-child > a:after {
        border: 0;
    }
```

This is the basic stuff. You should work a little to use it for your purpose.

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/994uG/)

[See updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nShMv/)

Comment: close, but first and last li are different then others

Comment: You helped me a lot, adding the opacity:0 to firts and last node I got what i needed. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/994uG/2/

Comment: @IvanPandžić I have also added an updated version..:) See updated demo .. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the css transform property: (not with *rotate* but *skew*)
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp), [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)
But it won't work in old browsers.

Code:

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  transform:skew(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:skew(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform:skew(-45deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this complete example I just created:

```
li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
    background: #4563DC;
    color: #111;
    position: relative;
}
li a.active {
    background: coral;
    color: #EEE;
}
li a:before, li a:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content:'';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 40px 14px 0 0;
    border-color: #4563DC transparent transparent transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
li a:after {
    left: auto;
    right: -14px;
    z-index: 2;
}
li a.active:after {
    border-top-color: coral;
}
li:first-of-type a:before {
    border-top-color: #FFF;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M8cWZ/

Answer (score 1):

The effect can be achieved with a skew transform, though it will require alternate fallback solutions for older browsers.

I've thrown together a quick example of your nav bar [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/huyPX/) which utilises a pseudo element on the anchor to apply the skew behaviour to.

```
transform: skew(-15deg,0);
-ms-transform: skew(-15deg,0);
-webkit-transform: skew(-15deg,0);
```