# Creating an angled CSS3 divider - 100% / Auto height

Tags: css, svg, css-transforms, angle

**I have checked these two posts: [Adjacent divs with angled borders? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568334/adjacent-divs-with-angled-borders) and [Shape with a slanted side (responsive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive) but those solutions posted do not adjust to 100% height of the container and I need this. I cannot find a solution to fit my scenario.**

I'm trying to replicate this behaviour the difference is the text inside this container can be of any height so I need the angle and container to adapt to fit any height (not a fixed height container):

[image]

Here's the code I'm using with a jSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qzma0r6k/1/

**CSS**

```
section {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
}
.diagonal:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 50%;
    background:pink;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="c-1">
  <div class="c-2 diagonal">
    <h1>Work with us</h1>
    <p>Scelerisque et parturient dis a erat cubilia congue sociosqu vel porta sem posuere a malesuada suspendisse id commodo. Dui consequat consectetur luctus odio nibh a vel sapien hendrerit ad a consectetur cursus a nisl posuere.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-image"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.c-1 {
  background: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.c-2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
}

.bg-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.diagonal {
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}

.diagonal:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-15deg) rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-15deg) rotate(180deg);
  transform: skewX(-15deg) rotate(180deg);
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<section class="c-1">
  <div class="c-2 diagonal">
    <h1>
    Work with us
    </h1>
    <p>
      Scelerisque et parturient dis a erat cubilia congue sociosqu vel porta sem posuere a malesuada suspendisse id commodo. Dui consequat consectetur luctus odio nibh a vel sapien hendrerit ad a consectetur cursus a nisl posuere. A cubilia varius dapibus non
      scelerisque aliquam imperdiet nec montes suspendisse orci potenti dignissim vestibulum venenatis sociosqu ullamcorper vestibulum scelerisque magna sem ultricies convallis cras. Ante sed elit tristique interdum hendrerit nascetur a cras suspendisse
      mi fermentum vestibulum auctor a taciti euismod ac non adipiscing a. Maecenas parturient a dui sodales vestibulum nisl nisi consequat cum lacus lobortis senectus metus at adipiscing cursus parturient a.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-image"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I'm looking for. Why would the title get cut off? Any way of fixing that?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Fixed.