# 'Cut' page on two sides

Tags: html, css

I want to 'cut' my page on two sides, something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngZrp.jpg

**DEMO**: https://jsfiddle.net/r2g0eyxf/3/

```
#left {
   background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/24353/pexels-photo.jpg);
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}

#right {
   background: url(http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/25-cars-worth-waiting-for-lp-ferrari-488gtb-photo-658256-s-original.jpg);
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}
```

But:

- I need this images responsive
- I want to create this 'slash'

How can I do this?

**EDIT**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568334) not solving my problem - I need it on full page and without space between images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjacent divs with angled borders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568334/adjacent-divs-with-angled-borders)

Comment: Why not just create that image?

Comment: @CharlieFish Because I'll create little 'slider' for this sides and I can't cut every image for this.

Comment: @David did you look at the link posted above? Did that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An hint would be to use transform and some padding.

[average example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwRNAN)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  color:turquoise;
  text-shadow:0 0  white;
  font-size:2em;
}

#left {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10%;
  height: 100%;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 60%;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left .content {
  background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/24353/pexels-photo.jpg);
  height: 100%;
}

#right .content {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/25-cars-worth-waiting-for-lp-ferrari-488gtb-photo-658256-s-original.jpg);
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  right: -10%;
  height: 100%;
}

#left .content, 
#right .content{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20%;
  margin: 0 -15%;
  transform: skew(15deg);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <div class="content">Content here</div>
</div>
<div id="right">
  <div class="content">Content here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`clip-path`](https://jsfiddle.net/), [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

```css
.clipped-img {
  position: relative;
}
.clipped-img img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
}
.clipped-img img:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon( 0% 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 0 100% );
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 0 100% );
}
.clipped-img img:nth-child(2) {
  right: 10%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon( 20% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100% );
  clip-path: polygon( 20% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100% );
}
```

```html
<div class="clipped-img">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300/FC0/">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300/CC0/">
</div>
```